# How i can get "item ID" column through "BDC Identity" column

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, custom-actions, external-list

I create external list for display external items from my wcf service and add custom action on that list EditForm through ClientObjectModel with this url:

```
"/ProcessSomething?siteUrl={SiteUrl}&listUrl={ListUrlDir}&itemId={ItemId}"
```

And add it on edit form.

But when i click on created button i recieve in my service non item ID field(that was defined as entity identifier in sharepoint designer), but i recieve "BDC Identity" value for item. Are there ways to retrieve my original Id field by "BDC Identity" or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a bad way. I decide to use Javascript object model.

Answer (score 0):

```
string bdcIdentity = "__bg40003300";
int id = Convert.ToInt32((EntityInstanceIdEncoder.DecodeEntityInstanceId(bdcIdentity)[0]));
```